# How does batch Echo parse variables in text

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to batch echo output value is from another file, and the content is a variable, how to parse it?

example:

env.bat

```
@echo off
set a=123
set b = 456

set dev_env=%a%
set prod_env=%b%
```

copy_env.bat

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 eol=: tokens=2,3 delims== " %%i in (.\env.bat) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set key=%%i
    set value=%%j

    echo !key!=!value! >> .\custom_variable.properties

    endlocal
)
```

output:  this is not what I want

```
dev_env=%a%
prod_env=%b%
```

output:  I want ....

```
dev_env=123
prod_env=456
```

Comment: You are basically parsing the BAT file and interpreting it like the command line processor? And implement that in Batch? Wow! I thought I do crazy stuff sometimes, but I never imagined this.

Comment: It semms crazy, Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You have to run env.bat at some point in the same instance of the command prompt that copy_env.bat is running in for `%a%` and `%b%` to actually exist. Stick a `call env.bat` at the top of copy_env.bat and also fix your third line in env.bat so that you're setting `%b%` correctly.

Comment: Other ideas: Run the batch file to actually set the environment variables. Or use a programming language like C++, C#, Python, Java or anything that can do real programming with string replacement etc.

Comment: @SomethingDark  thank you for your answer , but I've tried that   It's null   eg: dev_env=""

Comment: Did you saw [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776542/778560) below? It _exactly_ answer your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call `env.bat` at some point so that the variables get set. Also, because `echo !key!=!value!` by itself will display `dev_env=%a%`, etc. you need to use `call` for a second pass of variable expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call env.bat
for /f "skip=1 eol=: tokens=2,3 delims== " %%i in (.\env.bat) do (
    set key=%%i
    set value=%%j

    call echo !key!=!value! >>.\custom_variable.properties
)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be solved without calling the batch file given enough time and effort.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - Sure, but there's no reason not to call it; as the name indicates, it's a script meant to initialize environment variables.

Comment: awesome !   it's correct

Comment: @SomethingDark  sorry  i hava a question   how to determines that the character is in the text repeat?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776542/778560) above...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Three points here:

- First of all, the lines in the `env.bat` file will *not* be executed inside the `env.bat` file itself, but in a *posterior* execution in the `copy_env.bat` file, right? For this reason, the values of `a` and `b` can *not* be taken via an "immediate" `%a%` and `%b%` expansion, but via a "delayed" `!a!` and `!b!` one instead.
- In second place, in `copy_env.bat` you have the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `endlocal` commands *inside* the `for /F` loop. This means that every value that is set in a for iteration will be lost when such an iteration ends. In order to preserve the values for the next `for /F` cycles, the setlocal-endlocal commands must be moved *outside* the `for /F` loop.
- Finally, you have this command: `echo !key!=!value!` that just *display* a line like `a=123`, but you have *not* a command with the *real* assignment of such a value. It is necessary to add the equivalent `set !key!=!value!` command in order to *store* such values for the posterior assignments.

The final working programs are these ones:

**env.bat:**

```
@echo off
set a=123
set b = 456

set dev_env=!a!
set prod_env=!b!
```

**copy_env.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 eol=: tokens=2,3 delims== " %%i in (.\env.bat) do (
    set key=%%i
    set value=%%j

    set !key!=!value!
    echo !key!=!value! >> .\custom_variable.properties

)
endlocal
```